# How to join table on ‘from’ alias?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, alias

How i can do something like this?

```
select * from  (generating table) alias_table
left join (select * from alias_table where id>5) alias_table_2
on alias_table.id=alias_table_2.id
```

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Use CTE (in general).

Comment: @Akina thanks, didn't know about it

Comment: Why do you think you can do this? A table alias doesn't name a table value, it names a representative row. PS This (as one can expect) is a faq. PS On syntax error read the manual re syntax & its semantics. PS For code questions give a [mre]. PS To use the left table alias as a representative row in defining the right table (ie with a dot, ie in a column reference) you may need to use LATERAL which may not be supported by a DBMS. PS Giving meaningless code does not communicate what you wish it meant. Giving code that doesn't return what you want does not communicate what you want. [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your MySQL version is no older than 8 then you can use common table expression as below:

```
WITH alias_table (column_list from generated table) AS (
    generating table
) 

select * from  alias_table
left join (select * from alias_table where id>5) alias_table_2
on alias_table.id=alias_table_2.id
```

In below link you will find a working example:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=2GJBwJNocB